# How can I make an independent static landing page for a joomla website

Tags: joomla, static

For [www.makevending.ro](http://www.makevending.ro/), I need to make a landing page with the purpose of organizing a contest.

I need this page to be static and completely independent from the Joomla admin. When a visitor provides his/her name and e-mail adress, he will be taken to the sites [HOMEPAGE](http://www.makevending.ro/).

Is  there a fast and safe way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

There are several plugins to do this on the JED website [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/landing-pages)

Comment: Do you know how to do this using Joomla! 2.5 or 3 core features?

Comment: I guess technically you could custom code it into the template - although it depends if you call coding it into the template core features. But this isn't a native Joomla feature and hence you should use a extension to give the extra functionality. Hence I think it's much better for it to be designed through a plugin for Joomla! Especially as some already exist!